# Password rule to checking against single character term

Tags: passwords

We have a password rule that checks against user attributes. The problem is that sometimes the attribute may be a single character like 'a'. In this case any password that contains 'a' will be rejected. How is this usually handled? Length check against the attribute value?

Answer (score 0):

Length check sounds great! Make sure the attribute is over 5 characters (3? 4? 6?) long and contained in the password before you reject it. It's your choice.